# Based on latest auto generated primary key not getting latest record from db using L2S

Tags: c#, linq

AOA, 
      I Have a problem on getting latest record from db for printing purpose based on auto generated primary key value. The purpose is to print the Newly created customer account detail. I am using reportviewer for printing purpose.

Firstly I save a new record in Customer Table using L2S and after SaveChanges() I get the latest Customer Primary key value and it works fine. Here is the code upto this.

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
DataSet1.CustomerAccountsDataTable dt = new DataSet1.CustomerAccountsDataTable();

CustomerAccount dtCustAcc = new CustomerAccount();

dtCustAcc.Name = tbCustName.Text;

<!-----------HERE ARE SOME MORE COLUMNS-----------> 

dc.CustomerAccounts.InsertOnSubmit(dtCustAcc);
dc.SubmitChanges();

int newCustId = int.Parse(dtCustAcc.CustID);
```

Then i pass this key value to print() method to get record form db based on this key value using LINQ query it also works for all other values other than newly generated key value that i have passed to print() method and on Linq query.

```
 var query =
            from cust in dc.CustomerAccounts
            where cust.CustID == newCustId
            select cust;

foreach (var d in query)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(d.CustID, d.Name, <-some more columns->);

}
```

It gives a very non-sense type or error "Specified Cast is Not valid" on foreach when i try to fill DataTable based on this key(newCustId) value query result using foreach.  Here is the code.

I use this datatable on reportviewr for printing purpose.

Note: I have checked the value of CustID in db is int. Both(db, newCustId) have exactly same types

I am using WPF,C#, VS2012, MS SQL SERVER 2012.

Can anybody help me plz?

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

One thing bothers me with your code : the `int newCustId = int.Parse(dtCustAcc.CustID);`. From this, I would think that the CustID property is a String, that will maybe explain you "Specified cast invalid" error....

Comment: No CustID is also int. I have check it.

Comment: Then you have another invalid cast error in your `dt.Rows.Add` statement. Errors are rarely nonsensical...

Comment: thank you @Laurent PerrucheJ .I have found the problem. It is due to change in designer table erroneously.